# sub Window panel into canvas scene with javafx

Tags: java, scala, javafx-2, javafx, java-canvas

With other engineer, we create a software (www.openmole.org) to create and run complex workflow on a computer grid. With the gui, you can create and modify some complex drag and drop workflow like this :

[image]

You can also see a video here : http://www.openmole.org/files/crazyCoconut.webm

As you can see, it's possible to drag and drop and connect each task with each other to make a complex workflow. When task move, arrow move to follow the mouse movement. When you click on a task, a new panel open, so you can choose some option to configure each task.

Actually we use a Netbean library to draw all of this on a unique scene, but in the future we want to make the same thing using javafx api/object.

So, do you think is it possible to open new Javafx `Nodes` sub windows with `Canvas` scene and api, like in this simple use case, representative of our use case ?

If not, do you know some other libraries to make this possible ?

[image]

Comment: Please try to elaborate a bit more, I didn't understand your question.

Comment: @sarcan i update the description, hope this is more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't place nodes in a [Canvas](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/canvas/Canvas.html) as it is not [Parent](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Parent.html), therefore it is a leaf [Node](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) and can have no children.

You could place the Canvas in a [Group](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Group.html) then add other Nodes to the group to overlay the Canvas.  Or you could take [snapshot](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#snapshot%28javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters,%20javafx.scene.image.WritableImage%29) images of nodes and place the snapshots in the canvas.  Though you may be better off rendering your UI in a standard scene graph rather than a canvas.

---

Here are some simple samples of similar, though different, UIs constructed using a standard scene graph: [Drag and drop connected nodes](https://gist.github.com/1441960) and [Dynamically add draggable and resizable children](https://gist.github.com/2724651).

[yWorks](http://www.yworks.com/en/index.html) created a JavaFX prototype of their excellent diagramming tool, so consider contacting them and licensing that rather than building your own.

See also the [Dex JavaFX Visualization Framework](http://www.javainc.com/projects/dex/Dex.html) which aids in data visualization UI construction.

Comment: I think the best approach here would be a Group for the task nodes placed above the canvas (drawing the connections) in a StackPane. The Snapshot idea would work too, of course, but rather limit the user interaction.

Comment: @jewelsea Do you have some example of library /function which help me to design this form of UI in a standard scene graph ?

Comment: Added sample links to answer